# JavaFX elements aligning right before animating

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

I'm developing a small GUI using JavaFX for an assignment. Having never used JavaFX before, most of what I've used or learned I've research myself. Most of my application runs smoothly, animations included.

I have a small user input section:

[image: Small user input GUI]

I'm trying to allow it to swipe left prior to loading the next scene, to give the user the impression of sequence. I achieved this using a ParallelTransition populated by TranslationTransitions in which I load all of these Nodes.

However, just slightly before it animates, it appears to align everything right.

[image: Alignment right before animation]

I have a feeling this is something to do with the container (AnchorPane) in which I'm placing these objects, or some undefined attribute which I'm not setting. As I'm learning this all on the fly, it's a bit difficult to narrow down. Can anyone give me an idea as to what is causing this and how I can retain the alignment? Each Node moves in the following way:

```
translateTransition.setFromX(node.getLayoutX());
translateTransition.setToX(node.getLayoutX()-500.00);
```

If I've left out any pertinent information, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my issue turned out to be the way I'm laying out my objects. Placing them in an arbitrary AnchorPane with only specific attributes to locate those items means that, upon animation, it will group those objects and animate them accordingly. It was the incorrect way to layout those nodes.

Instead, I've placed them in a VBox which has two advantages.

1. I can align the contents of that VBox centre, so I need not specify the exact layout attributes of the elements.
2. I can animate using the single VBox, as opposed to the all the elements in a ParallelTransition. As a result, a single TranslateTransition on the VBox node will suffice!